# wireless adaper using python

Tags: python, networking, adapter

I am trying to find the network adapter id( a guid) of a computer using python.
Any idea?

Thanks
Sudhanshu

Comment: Which OS are talking about? And are you trying to find the adapter's MAC address?

Comment: I am trying to do it on pc and mac.

Comment: i am not sure if the guid is same as MAC address. but i feel both are different. i may be wrong.

Comment: 'PC' and 'mac' are hardware platforms. You need to tell us which operating system you are using. You also need to tell us what you mean by "GUID of the network adapter", if you do not mean its MAC address. If you do not know, you can provide an example of one such GUID from another source.

Comment: I am looking to do this on mac 10.6.x and 10.5.x and on win7 and xp.

Comment: if you see the link below it has the answer for the windows but not for the mac. on the win the mac id will be of the form {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx} (curly braces will be a part of the guid) while on the mac it will be same but without the braces.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this (manually)?

http://forum.notebookreview.com/windows-os-software/302638-how-find-network-adapter-guid.html

If it works, you can then try coding it in Python via pywin32

Comment: Thanks that is what I am looking for but one issue is that how will you know from the example above which one is the wireless and which one is wired. Any clue?

Comment: @sudhanshu: I don't think there is an absolute answer to this; however, in each adapter's entry there is a Description string. If this string contains 'wireless' or 'wifi' or '802.11', you can probably assume is wireless!